# PostgreSQL : total length of roads in polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have 2 tables : wgo (lines) and wbn (polygons)
With this code, I can display the length of each road inside a polygon. If I have a polygon with 2 roads in it, as a result I get 2 rows with the 2 lengths displayed.

But what I really want, is the total length of roads in the polygon, so I want to SUM them up.. How can this be done ?

```
SELECT wbn_uidn, wgo_uidn, ST_Length(ST_Intersection(wgo_geom,wbn_geom))
FROM wbn, wgo
WHERE ST_Intersects(wgo_geom,wbn_geom)='t'
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/315769/120129

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT wbn_uidn, sum(ST_Length(ST_Intersection(wgo_geom,wbn_geom)))
FROM wbn, wgo
WHERE ST_Intersects(wgo_geom,wbn_geom) 
GROUP BY wbn_uidn;
```