# Storing distance between two points in KM

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0

I am very new to PostgreSQL and PostGIS. I am filtering a collection of messages based on their distance from a point which works great, but I would like to be able to store the distance between the two points in km as well. I've tried a few different things with no luck.

This is the function I am using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.search_posts_near_user(userid integer, distance_kms double precision)
 RETURNS SETOF geo_posts
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
  SELECT  A.user_id, A.location,
  (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(B)) FROM post B
   WHERE (
     ST_Distance_SPHERE(B.location::Geometry,A.location::Geometry) /1000) < distance_kms
   ) AS nearby_posts
  FROM user_location A where A.user_id = userid;

$function$
```

Comment: Bring your type to geography and you will get the distance in meters, for example, as here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/315769/120129

Comment: shouldn't `ST_Distance_SPHERE(B.location::Geometry,A.location::Geometry)` be the distance? what I would like to do is do an INSERT with this value.

Comment: Which coordinate system do you work in: geographic EPSG:4326 or rectangular?

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Sphere.html

Comment: Be sure to review the associated answers to your question on the right side of the interface...